# assert triggered too late

Tags: events, printing, assert, modelica

Please consider the following Modelica example model:

```
model Detection2
  Real x = (1-2*time)*1e5;
  parameter Real x_min=0.1;
  Real y;

equation 
  y = max(x,x_min);
  assert(y>x_min, "(assert) triggered at t = " + String(time), level=AssertionLevel.warning);
  when y <= x_min then
      Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("(when) triggered at t = " + String(time));
  end when;
  annotation (experiment(StopTime=1));
end Detection2;
```

When I simulate it (in Dymola 2019FD01), I get the following results:
[image]

Results look as expected, but both the assert message and the print statement print the wrong time, they always print the stop time, not the time I expected!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Why didn't it trigger before the end? The reason is that for numerical reasons solvers create events for such relations, and don't want too many events, and thus consider `y>x_min` true as long as it is "almost true", i.e. that `y>x_min-eps`, for some small epsilon. This is explained in section 8.5 Events and Synchronization of the specification. https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch8.html#events-and-synchronization
2. Why did it trigger at the end? The reason is that there is an event at the end of the simulation, because the model may contain the `terminal` operator. At an event the comparisons are treated more literally.

If you had used `x>x_min` and `x<=x_min` instead it would have worked as you expected.

Alternatively if you had used `y = if x>=x_min then x else x_min` then y might be slightly below `x_min`, but the messages would trigger.